# how to match two strings in c

Tags: c, string

How to check whether  string `"HEAA5"`  matches any of  the strings (`"HE+++"` , `"HEAA+"`,`"HEA++"`,`"HC+++"`,`"HCA++"`) in given array where `+` indicates any character .

Here in this example `HEAA5` matches `HE+++`,`HEAA+`,`HEA++`.

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple function to compare two strings for equality that skips the comparison when there is a `+` in the pattern.

The algorithm I'm using is:

- Scan `str` and `pattern` in parallel as long as neither one has reached their end (NULL).
- If the current `pattern`character is `+` then continue scanning.
- If the current `str` and `pattern` characters don't match then return false.
- When scanning is done return true if **both** strings reached their end, otherwise return false since one of them has unmatched characters remaining.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int match(const char *str, const char *pattern)
{
    for (; *str && *pattern; ++str, ++pattern) {
        if (*pattern == '+') continue;
        if (*str != *pattern) return 0;
    }
    return !(*str || *pattern);
}

int main()
{
    const char *str = "HEAA5";
    const char *pattern[] = { "HE+++", "HEAA+", "HEA++", "HC+++", "HCA++" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%s %s %d\n", str, pattern[i], match(str, pattern[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[(Live demo here)](http://ideone.com/MQP1dO)

Comment: +1 i think this one should be the right direction of answer to question.

Answer (score 0):

String is an array of characters in C.So all you have to do is to check whether each character of `HEAA5`== each character of the inputted string.Also check if the inputted string is a 5 letter string by using `strlen`.If the character of the inputted string is an `'+'`,check the next letter of the string.

An alternative way to do this when there is no `'+'` in the inputted string would be to use [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) as mentioned in the comments.